# How to override Element prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to override one Element.prototype function:

```
  const originalAppendChild = Element.prototype.appendChild;

  Element.prototype.appendChild = (el) => {
    console.log("Override!!!");
    return originalAppendChild.apply(this, [el]);
  };
```

But when I then run:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
```

I get:

```
Override!!!
VM406:5 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at HTMLBodyElement.Element.appendChild (<anonymous>:5:36)
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

Where line 5:36 refers to the `.apply(this, [el]);` part. Which means it this the `apply` method who is throwing this error.

I have tried to figure out, and it seems the problem comes from `this`, but I am at loss how to properly set it (if that's the cause).

Comment: fat arrow changes this,

Comment: Don't define member methods with arrow functions, define them with pre-ES2015 function expresions, which have their own lexical `this` and `arguments` as opposed to arrow functions.

Comment: You can also use `call` instead of `apply` if you want to forward one argument.

Comment: OMG, I would never have guessed this one. Is there any documentation I should have read and I missed? How did you know the arrow function was the culprit? This is soooo dark...!

Comment: @PedroD there is plenty of documentation on the subject, such as [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)